# Mysql check WHERE field IN (multiple_values)

Tags: php, mysql

Good morning all,

I'm trying to use a smarty MySql one-line that will do the thing for me instead of using more PHP code or multiple sql lines...so here it goes.

I have an old style mysql (which i will convert soon to PDO*) that goes like this :

```
$query_list_releases = "SELECT * from mya_projects WHERE shared_to IN ('".$_id."') ORDER by deadline ASC";
```

but **shared_to** field format is something like 1,3,15,16 or 1,4,6 (id's separated by commas). If **shared_to** is just one number, it works, because it searches the rows where shared_to == to my $_id. But the tricky part comes when shared_to is more than 1 number, all separated with commas.

I need to select all the rows where I find say "1" in the shared_to column.

Do anyone has any ideea how should I proceed?

Comment: Your database is not properly normalized, that's why you're having this issue.

Comment: i chose to add friends_ids that each thing is shared to as comma separated, instead of individual rows, because i ported a code from another project and it was thought like that. If it will bother me, i will switch to row inserted for each shared item. thanks man.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)**  in mysql

```
SELECT * from mya_projects
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( id, shared_to)
ORDER by deadline ASC
```

Comment: Important to note is that this should not be used for big tables as it must inspect all rows to build the result set.

Comment: well, i did a quick calculation and topped the results to a possible big table that will be formed in around 3 years. will 2 million results be noted as a big table ?

Comment: @AdrianTanase 2 million records is enough to feel the difference :)

Comment: @Jack well then...how do you think I should proceed?...should i have say 10 different rows of data containing the id's instead of 1 column containing 10 id's separated with commas ? i understand that this function FIND_IN_SET is searching through all the say "million" rows in the table...but if i already have 1 million rows in this table multiplying with average 10 "shares to particular users" / row it will become 10 million, this new table....

Comment: @AdrianTanase The difference would be that you can use an optimized index; you also have the possibility to partition tables or apply other horizontal scaling practices.

Comment: @Jack the optimized index crossed my mind while writing you back the comment, true, it will add hdd space to database but it would go faster than what i'm using right now...i think in the end i will modify the way i use shared_to field to a new table with independent rows....good point....can you point me to any resources about partitioning tables or "horizontal scaling" practices ? thanks